# Adding a Texture to ExtrudeGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

**three.js v53**

In three.js v 53 on JSFiddle, making a custom shape, extruding it and applying a texture and wireframe shows the extruded faces being whole, complete squares.

JSFiddle: [custom shape extruded in v53 with complete, un-split extrusion faces](http://jsfiddle.net/pydmnvo8/2/)

**three.js v74**

The exact same code but three.js v 74 splits the extrude faces into triangles.

JSFiddle: [custom shape extruded in v74 with segmented (into triangles) extrusion faces](http://jsfiddle.net/vxr3Ljf3/3/)

**Question 1:** how can I eliminate the segmentation into triangles of the extruded faces in v74?

**Bonus Question 2:** how can I eliminate the segmentation into triangles on the main face of my shape that I extrude (what I was originally trying to solve when I noticed the extrusion differences between three.js versions)

Both are making my texturing journey harder. Many thanks.

Code for both JSFiddles:

(Some code borrowed from another JS Fiddle but I can't find it again to credit)

```
/****
Create the texture as I can't use an image on my server
*****/
var canvas = document.getElementById("texture"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 50;
canvas.height = 50;

context.strokeStyle = "#5588ff";
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.moveTo(0, 10);
context.lineTo(50, 10);
context.moveTo(0, 20);
context.lineTo(50, 20);
context.moveTo(0, 30);
context.lineTo(50, 30);
context.moveTo(0, 40);
context.lineTo(50, 40);
context.stroke();
/***********/

var scene, camera, renderer, shape;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 200;
scene.add(this.camera);

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(light);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true, alpha:true
});
document.getElementById("scene").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.setSize(document.getElementById("scene").scrollWidth, document.getElementById("scene").scrollHeight);



var points = []

points.push(new THREE.Vector2(100, 0));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(100, 60));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(40, 90));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(-40, 90));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(-100, 60));
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(-100, 0));

// var path = new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(45, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-45, 0, 0));

var extrusionSettings = {
  steps: 1,
  bevelEnabled: false,
  amount: 90
};

shape = new THREE.Shape(points);
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrusionSettings),
  texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xFF00FF,
  map: texture
});

// *** UVMapping stuff I copied off an example. I don't know what it's doing but the texture won't work without it.
geometry.faceUvs = [
  []
];
geometry.faceVertexUvs = [
  []
];

for (var f = 0; f < geometry.faces.length; f++) {

  var faceuv = [
    new THREE.Vector2(0, 1),
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 1),
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 0),
    new THREE.Vector2(0, 0)
  ];

  geometry.faceUvs[0].push(new THREE.Vector2(0, 1));
  geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push(faceuv);
}

// add a wireframe to highlight the segmentation (or lack of in this v53 demo)
mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, [material, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x000000,
  wireframe: true,
  transparent: true
})]);
mesh.position.z = -50;
mesh.position.y = -40;
mesh.rotation.y = 0.8;
mesh.rotation.z = 0.4;

scene.add(mesh);


animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
  mesh.rotation.x += 0.02;

};
animate();
```

Comment: FYI - Older versions of three.js supported quad faces. Now, three.js supports only triangluar faces. Use `THREE.EdgesHelper` if you want a wireframe without diagonals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`THREE.ExtrudeGeometry` creates default UVs for you based on the coordinates of the extruded shape. (Look at the geometry of the extruded shape and inspect the UVs that are computed for you.)

The auto-generated UVs will likely be outside the normal range of [ 0, 1 ]. You can accommodate that by using a pattern like so:

```
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.offset.set( 0, 0.5 );
texture.repeat.set( 0.01, 0.01 );
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vxr3Ljf3/4/

Alternatively, you can specify your own custom UV generator like so:

```
var extrusionSettings = {
  steps: 1,
  bevelEnabled: false,
  amount: 90,
  UVGenerator: myUVGenerator
};
```

Base your custom UV generator on `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.WorldUVGenerator`.

three.js r.74

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much @WestLangley, that is perfect. Adding the texture wrapping and repeating, and removing the UV stuff I copied blindly off the internet has solved the problem of the texturing following the triangular faces. As your code shows, it's not the faces that are the problem but how the texture is treated across the whole. You've just levelled up my knowledge of texturing. Thank you again.