# texture map doesn't work properly in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I made a shape and extruded it. here is the code:

```
import wood from "./wood_texture.jpg"

let generate_box = (width, height, depth) => {
    let extrudeSettings = {
        depth: depth,
        bevelEnabled: false,
    }
    
    const shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape.lineTo( 0, this.height );
    shape.lineTo( width, this.height );
    shape.lineTo( width, 0 );
    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);
    return geometry

};
let box_geo = generate_box(0.5, 2.2, 0.35)
let textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
let material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: "rgb(248, 
247, 247)", map: textureLoader.load(wood)} )

box_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(box_geo, material)
scene.add(box_mesh)
```

and this is the result
[image]

As can be seen, the texture hasn't been mapped correctly. Ideally, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35528109/1461008